# Как сделать вход гостя по имени на сайт?

Tags: php, cookie, сессия

Здравствуйте, помогите решить такой вопрос. Как сделать вход пользователя на сайт как гостя, только по введенному им имени.

Вот допустим есть файл `Index` с формой ввода и файл `list` с данными которые можно получить, только введя имя, а иначе будет выдаваться `ошибка 403`.

Как это реализовать, где хранить введенное имя пользователя и проверять его?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<p>войдите как гость:</p>
    <form method="POST"  id="guest-form">
        <div class>
            <label for="lg" class="sr-only">Введите имя</label>
            <input type="text" name="guest-name" id="lg" class="form-control" placeholder="Имя">
        </div>

        <input id="btn_login" class="btn btn-custom btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" value="Отправить" name="submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Все что есть это форма входа, главный вопрос состоит в том, как при вводе имени пользователя, после нажатия на кнопку "Отправить", сделать переадресацию на страницу `list.php`, где вывести пользователю `Привет "Введенное имя"` и дать пользователю доступ к данным, которые находятся в этом файле. Но если, заходить на `list.php` на прямую, выдавать ошибку 403.

Ошибку можно выдать с помощью `header("Status: 403 Svoboden");`?

Comment: "Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу."

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $username = $_POST["guest-name"];
    echo "$username";
    $_SESSION['name'] = $username;
    header("Location: list.php");
}
```

Делается путем создания сессии